# Issue When FullCalendar Has 2-months in Screen

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

As you can see from below "Correct Scenario", "Wrong Scenario" and "Code".

When my 15-days calendar shows;

2-months in one screen which is the wrong scenario below; calendar splits itself by 2(months) and then, split each month to how days it needs to show. (13 days for February, 2 days for March.)
1-month in one screen which is the correct scenario below; calendar splits itself by only days which everything is fine.
So, when calendar has 2-months to show in screen, it's splitting wrongly.

How could we solve this issue?

CORRECT SCENARIO
[Correct Scenario SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEq1N.png)

WRONG SCENARIO
[Wrong Scenario SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhqBZ.png)

Here is the code;

```
_this.Calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(div, {
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        locale: 'tr',
        now: today,
        scrollTime: '00:00',
        editable: false,            
        selectable: true,
        aspectRatio: 1.8,
        height: "100%",

        initialView: 'resourceTimelineFourDays',
        views: {
            resourceTimelineFourDays: {
                type: 'resourceTimeline',
                duration: { days: daycount },
                slotLabelInterval: { hours: 24 },
                slotLabelFormat: [
                    { month: 'long', year: 'numeric' },
                    { weekday: 'short', day: 'numeric' }
                ],
                buttonText: 'Odalar'
            }
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your `slotLabelFormat` - **requires Moment.js** - https://momentjs.com/

```
slotLabelFormat: [ function(date) { return moment(date.date).format('MMM') }, function(date) { return moment(date.date).format('D') } ]
```

change the `.format` values to suit what you want.

you can put anything you like in the `function(date) {}` parts, so you don't have to use Moment.js, if you can manipulate the `date` to what you want in another way.